# Correct Procedure is not executed?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

```
public void GettraderwiseLiftingRecords()
{

    DataTable dtLEtraderReport = new DataTable();
    dtLEtraderReport.Clear();
    dtLEtraderReport = objhatcheryBAL.GetchicksaledueReport();
    GVTraderdueReport.DataSource = dtLEtraderReport;
    GVTraderdueReport.DataBind(); 
}
```

I called `GettraderwiseLiftingRecords()` method in page load. If debug it goes directly to this method. When `GetchicksaledueReport()` method is executed ,then it takes Master page Login Details procedure. Here "dtLEtraderReport" get Login details. Why it's taken another details?

Finally I am getting an exception like "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'name'"....

Please help me...

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
{
    if (Session["username"] != null)
    {
        string pageName = Page.Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Substring(Page.Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        DataTable dtFeatures5 = new DataTable();
        dtFeatures5.Clear();
        ////da = new SqlDataAdapter("Exec Sp_GetUserModuleFeatures '" + Session["UserType"].ToString() + "'", con);
        ////da.Fill(dtFeatures);
        objMatermenuPL.usertype = Session["UserType"].ToString();
        dtFeatures5 = objMastermenuBAL.GetMastermenu(objMatermenuPL);

        DataView dt = new DataView(dtFeatures5);
        dt.Sort = "fld_feature ASC";

        if (dtFeatures5 != null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code for GetchicksaledueReport(). Looks like you have not really defined the problem completely.

Comment: Editing your question and adding it there will be good idea.

Comment: see,it's getting correct value some time..but some times "Login" details

Comment: If you are using any ajax control into your page, than first remove it or comment  and try it without them.

Comment: You seem to have two questions there "Why it's taken another details" and an error that you are getting. First for the error you should post your aspx page and mention what GetchicksaledueReport() returns (structure if possible). For your first question you must mention what was expected, what is the content of GetchicksaledueReport() function. That way people could provide more appropriate answers

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var data = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("K_HM_GetChickamounttogrid");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = connection;

    var dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        dataAdaptor.Fill(data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.LogError(e);
    }
}

return data;
```

It is the same thing as yours but more clear, probably.

Comment: Good advice with the catch block!  the original code was swallowing the information needed for identifying the problem.

Comment: mate, it is a sample method. We log the errors here. Kindly, comment it out.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET, when it hits an error, sometimes the debugger will seem to detach and just continue displaying a page.  This is why it is going into your login page.  It is the next step after the page_load has failed.  So the server has moved on to the next page load event.  Your (empty) catch block is making it harder for you to see (and debug) the real cause of this problem.

The error about "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView'"... is probably because your page has a datagrid (or another bound property) that binds to a column/element 'name'.  Use the editor to search for "name" in the .aspx page.  Then debug the code that binds to it.  Make sure there is a column "Name" in the result set.  Otherwise, comment out that column in your data grid (or whatever data binding that is calling it), to confirm what I'm saying.

(since you updated your code) Good, you removed the empty catch block.
I cannot see the source behind your datagrid, but your error message is saying that your dataset does not contain a column "Name" but your datagrid is expecting a column "Name".
Based on your reply chain (below) with @Dilip, it sounds like you might have a data-bound field on your master page and the error is there.  Which would explain why this error might be showing up anywhere at any time.

Looking at your second block of code, if your session expires, none of this code will run.  If your master page has a datagrid (or another data-bound field), you might get an error because there is no data to bind.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL Stored Procedure, I am sure the query which return will have escape column such as **ID, name**, etc.

Also check the properties of "GVTraderdueReport" does it have also escape characters Field / Properties of SQL Queries.

Answer (score 1):

You may give the wrong column name in you procedure check it once again , if it not work reply me i can suggest more thing

Comment: thanks for replay dilip...you are right,if i gave wrong column name...but some time same procedure is executed normally..but some times i got this exception

Comment: can you define any column in datagrid at design time?

Comment: This exception comes not only this procedure,not only this page..complete application faced this exception...

Comment: Master pages we use Login credentials with single procedure..it's may happens i think..

Comment: You gives dataTable reference in master page and used it in other page , that may conflict so you can remove such dependency from master page and put it at different page.

Comment: You can not directly pass the sp name in sqlDataAdapter instead you need to create sqlCommand first give the type of that command as storedprocedure and pass the object of command to sqlDataAdapter.